# Jquery selector not working on page load but works after scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this jquery script which detects the element top position and adds an animation if it is visible on the screen. This works only if I scroll the screen a little. But it doesn't adding the animation when the page loads.

So I tried logging the **tiles** selector. It is not selecting the elements with the class **fadeInTile** when the page loads, but only after scrolling the screen a little i can see all the elements with that class name.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function scrollCb() {
        var tiles = $(".fadeInTile").not(".animated")
        var $window = $(window);

        var docViewTop = $window.scrollTop();
        var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $window.height();
        console.log(tiles)

        tiles.each(function (i) {
            var $this = $(this);
            var elemTop = $this.offset().top;

            if ((elemTop <= (docViewBottom - 70))) {
                $this.addClass("animated").addClass("fadeInUp");
            }
        });
    }
    $(window).scroll(scrollCb)
    scrollCb()
})
```

**.fadeInTile**

```
.fadeInTile{
    opacity: 0;
}
```

**EDIT**
I created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/scza61pq/ and it works fine. But it is not working in my page. My website is build on angularjs Is that something to do with this?

Comment: can you add this to a jsfiddle!

Comment: Works fine if I create it myself: http://jsfiddle.net/bL562oyL/

Answer (score 2):

use `$j=jQuery.noConflict();` and use `$j` selector instead of `$`

Comment: it is not working. It gives me an error '$j is not a function'. Should I change all the '$' to '$j' or just the selector?

Comment: you have to use $j instead of $ allover function and above function you have to write noConflict code

Answer (score 2):

Just keep your function out of ready. It might work

```
function scrollCb() {
        var tiles = $(".fadeInTile").not(".animated")
        var $window = $(window);

        var docViewTop = $window.scrollTop();
        var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $window.height();
        console.log(tiles)

        tiles.each(function (i) {
            var $this = $(this);
            var elemTop = $this.offset().top;

            if ((elemTop <= (docViewBottom - 70))) {
                $this.addClass("animated").addClass("fadeInUp");
            }
        });
    }
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).scroll(scrollCb)
    scrollCb()
})
```

Comment: can you just post your html